# git add . command taking too much time more than 30 minutes

Tags: git, git-commit

`git add .` taking too much time [image of vs code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTYFg.png)

I tried :

```
    git init
```

```
    git add .
```

```
git commit -m "protected routes with authguard service"
```

now it's working but its taking too much time more than 30 minutes..

Comment: thank you team, This issue is resolved by adding .gitignore file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should be uploading the node_modules folder.
Make a `.gitignore` file in the main directory and add `/node_modules` in it so it doesn't upload the folder to the git every time.